# Пагинация + сортировка по алфавиту

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, сортировка, frontend, пагинация

Реально ли вообще сделать пагинацию + сортировку по алфавиту однвоременно на клиенте? Тип, ты получаешь Н-ное кол-во записей, сортируешь, потом, когда листаешь до определенного ммоента на странице, запрашиваешь ещё, но , типа, если отсортировать теперь все записи ещё раз, то некоторые могут в самое анчало страницы попасть (например, если некоторые новые полученне записи имеют в начале букву А), и ты их не увидишь. Мб , тогда, такую сортировку проводят на бекенде?

Comment: Реально и что? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Не понятны ваши проблемы. Вы почему-то считаете это сложным занятием. Сортировка это порядок элементов в наборе данных. А пагинация это выборка элементов из этого списка.

Конечно иногда программисты делают неверно совмещая сортировку и пагинация клиентскую и серверную. Вам нужно определиться с выбором либо клиентская либо серверная сортировка/выборка во избежании путаниц с данными.

Сортировку/фильтрацию/пагинацию нужно выполнять там где у вас все данные. Если вы подкачали все на клиенте то там, если нет то вот тут и нужны серверные операции.

Comment: Ну смотрите. Я, инициализировав приложение, получил список песен (В, А, Б) Далее, я ставлю сортировку по алфавиту, и эти песни моментально становятся упорядоченными (А, Б, В). Далее, пролистывая страницу, при пересечении определенной точки, я запрашиваю ещё песни. (А, Б, В + Д, А, Г)  Далее, я либо сортирую полученные песни, либо сортирую уже все имеющиеся песни и получаю либо (А, Б, В, А, Г, Д), либо (А, А, Б, В, Г, Д). Но, как вы моежете заметить, оба случая неверны. Остается только один вариант - запросить сразу ВСЕ песни с бека и отсортировав, отображать их поочередно. Или как?

Comment: Случай (А, А, Б, В, Г, Д) неверен, потому как на момент запроса новых песен я буду на песне В, и, запросив Д, А, Г, а затем отсортировав, по-факту, не увижу новую песню А, ибо она переместится в начало списка песен

Comment: Поймите не верно делать сортировку на кусочке данных. Это порождает проблемы такого рода. Сортировку делают на всем наборе а не на части

Comment: Получите весь список отсортируйте потом сделайте пагинацию.

Comment: Если список у вас меняется что может быть. То на каждом запросе обновляется сначала полный список затем сортируют затем делают пагинацию

Comment: Ну представьте вы стоите на последней странице. Сделали сортировку. Если у вас по логике остаться на этой странице то логично вы не увидите те данные которые были до сортировки.

Comment: ну да. Вот я и говорю, что, видимо, придется запрашивать прям все песни с бека

Comment: Необязательно. Я описал вам когда в этом есть необходимость. Ну представьте песен несколько миллионов. Вам зачем их тянуть на клиент. Держите преспокойно его на сервере и получайте страницы уже с сервера

Comment: Сортируйте там где все данные. Если скачали на клиент то там если нет то на сервере